# Set horizontal scrollbar position to the rightmost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making a website where you read articles by scrolling towards right similar to the windows 10 desktop apps.

I want to make sure that when the article loads, the page should display the end of the article, i.e.; the scrollbar must be to the rightmost and then animate the scrollbar to move to the left (i.e.; towards the beginning of the article) so that first time users know about the reading layout.

I'm also using CSS `columns` to break down the articles into columns.
I tried using `scrollLeft()` to set scrollbar position to the rightmost but I don't know how to calculate the width of the article spanning horizontally

How can I do this?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="entry-content">
...

...

...

</div>
```

contains the article

**CSS :**

```
.entry-content {
    column-count: 3;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Here is the link to the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9ynasean/)

Comment: did you try getting its width using jQuery? (try `$(".entry-content").width()` )

Comment: Yes, it shows the width of `.entry-content` and not the width of the overflowing content horizontally due to `columns`

Comment: So you what horizontal scrolling and load page with scroll to end ? what is your content looks like ?

Comment: This is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9ynasean/

Comment: are you expecting this ? https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/9ynasean/1/

Comment: i dont understand with this word? 
animate the scrollbar to move to the left = auto scrolling ?

Comment: @KishoreSahas, exactly that. Didn't know it was that easy. Please make it an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need get the full width of the element.

```
   var left = $('.entry-content').width();
   $('.entry-content').scrollLeft(left);
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/9ynasean/1/